# How to fetch nested entities despite duplicates in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, inner-join

I have DB with translations dictionary. It has entity "Word" and "Translation". Each translation is linked to one "source" word and one "target" word -- for example I could have translation with "cat" (English) and "kot" (Polish) which means "cat" translates to "kot", and "kot" translates to "cat".

When searching for given phrase (e.g. "cat") in dictionary I would like to fetch `Word` entity for this phrase and all words it is translated to. So the query I started from looks like this:

```
Word[] words = ctx.Words
  .Include(it => it.TranslationSrcWords) 
  .ThenInclude(it => it.SrcWord)
  .Include(it => it.TranslationDstWords)
  .ThenInclude(it => it.DstWord)
  ...
```

With such code I get error:

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance.

Of course the above query would result with word duplicates -- one fetched right at the start (`ctx.Words`) and then either from `SrcWord` or `DstWord` (one side of the translation has to point back to the word being found).

EF "optimization" forces me to either suppress the error or comment out nested include -- in both cases it leads to partial fetch. I.e. when I look for "cat" instead of getting translations like:

```
("cat", "kot")
```

I get translations like:

```
("cat", null)
```

The "cat" is fixed up indeed by EF, and `null` because I had to skip nested include so there is simply no data.

How to solve it, i.e. fetch data in one take?

*Full repo is here: https://codeberg.org/macias/lala/src/branch/master Simplified models:*

```
public sealed class Word
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Phrase { get; set; } = null!;

    public  ICollection<Translation> TranslationDstWords { get; set; } = default!;
    public  ICollection<Translation> TranslationSrcWords { get; set; } = default!;
}

public sealed class Translation
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long SrcWordId { get; set; }
    public long DstWordId { get; set; }

    public  Word DstWord { get; set; } = null!;
    public  Word SrcWord { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: can you add the models to your question ?  if the word is 'cat' do you have to search in src and dest or do you know where to search ?

Comment: Maybe a raw sql query is better suited for the job.

Comment: @jeb, If I start from `Translation` entity I would then to have search at source and target words (this is why I start with `ctx.Words` to have `Word` as top/root entity). Raw SQL would work for sure, I would like to find out if this is doable using EF (in single query).

Comment: Let's say the Phrase is 'Foo' and it is found in [en] now you want all translations for it correct ? 
Lets's say 'Foo' is found in [en] and [pl] what should happen ? Do you want all translations for both entries ?

Comment: @jeb, in both cases the answer is "yes" :-). I would like to find given `Word` entry, with `Translation` entries set, and within `Translation` with `Word` set as well. Maybe this diagram would help? "cat <- cat/kot trans <- CAT -> cat/kot trans -> kot" (the middle "cat" is the phrase searched for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because when you include one navigation side of a relationship (either collection or reference), the other side (aka inverse) navigation is automatically included by EF Core.

In your sample, both

```cs
.Include(it => it.TranslationSrcWords) 
    .ThenInclude(it => it.SrcWord)
```

and

```cs
.Include(it => it.TranslationDstWords) 
    .ThenInclude(it => it.DstWord)
```

*independently* violate that rule and will cause the aforementioned exception.

What you really need is to `ThenInclude` navigations *other* than the inverse. For instance:

```cs
.Include(it => it.TranslationSrcWords) 
    .ThenInclude(it => it.DstWord)
```

and

```cs
.Include(it => it.TranslationDstWords) 
    .ThenInclude(it => it.SrcWord)
```

This in general does what you need without EF Core errors.

However, in this particular case the two many-to-one relationships effectively form single many-to-many *self* relationships. And taking into account that including navigation (with both `Include` or `ThenInclude`) automatically includes the inverse, you can easily see that it will be enough to include in the query just one of the above `Include` / `ThenInclude` requests. Because

```cs
Include(word => word.TranslationSrcWords)
```

automatically includes `translation.SrcWord`. Then

```cs
ThenInclude(translation => translation.DstWord)
```

automatically includes `translation.DstWord.TranslationDstWords`, and the cycle is closed.

Shortly, for this example I would suggest including only one of the above `Include` / `ThenInclude` pairs. You can include both if you wish, and there won't be an error, but it would lead to much more inefficient SQL, and the result will be the same.

Comment: Many thanks. I have to use both include though. Let's say you want to find "cat" -- for some translations it would play role of source word, but for some as target word. So lets say I have translations stored (effectively) as "cat-kot" and "gato-cat", with just one Include+ThenInclude I would get to first one, not the latter, because it is stored in "opposite" way. But this is minor remark, the point is the idea of completing the cycles works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

"When searching for given word in dictionary I would like to fetch this word and all words it is translated to":

```
Translation[] translations = ctx.Translations.Where(w => w.SrcWord == givenword).ToArray();
```

To advance the solution I can propose to use two structures: Word(Wordid,Word) and Translation(Srcid,Tgtid). Translation should have foreign keys for both source and target Words. For two languages 4 tables are reqired: Word[] English, Polish; Translation[] EngPol, PolEng.

```
string[] TranslateE2P(string word) {
    return ctx.EngPol.Where(w => w.SrcidNavigation.Word == word).Select(s => s.TgtidNavigation.Word).ToArray();
}
```

To get translations for all words in a phrase at once use GroupJoin https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=net-7.0.

**UPD** Ok, let's look at another solution. Word(Wordid,Langid,Word) and Translation(Srcid,Tgtid). Everything is combined into Words and Translations. Here is the sample app to demonstrate this concept:

```
// .NET FW 4.8, C# 5.0
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace NsTranslator {
    class Language {
        string ln; int lid;
        public Language (string l, int i) { ln = l; lid = i; }
        public string LanguageName { get { return ln; } }
        public int LanguageID { get { return lid; } }
    }
    class Word {
        string wn; int lid; int wid;
        public Word (string w, int li, int wi) { wn = w; lid = li; wid = wi; }
        public string WordName { get { return wn; } }
        public int LangId { get { return lid; } }
        public int WordId { get { return wid; } }
    }
    class Translation {
        int sid; int tid;
        public Translation (int si, int ti) { sid = si; tid = ti; }
        public int SrcId { get { return sid; } }
        public int TgtId { get { return tid; } }
    }
    class Translator {
        static List<Language> lngs;
        static List<Word> words;
        static List<Translation> trns;
        static void Main() {
            lngs = new List<Language>() { new Language("English", 1)
                , new Language("Polish", 2)
                , new Language("Spanish", 3)
                , new Language("Esperanto", 4)
            };  
            words = new List<Word>() { new Word("cat", 1, 1)
                , new Word("kot", 2, 2)
                , new Word("kote", 2, 3)
                , new Word("kotiara", 2, 4)
                , new Word("gato", 3, 5)
                , new Word("gata", 3, 6)
                , new Word("felino", 3, 7)
                , new Word("goes", 1, 8)
                , new Word("va", 3, 9)
                , new Word("idzie", 2, 10)
                , new Word("cat", 4, 11)
            }; 
            trns = new List<Translation>() { new Translation(1, 2)
                , new Translation(1, 3)
                , new Translation(1, 4)
                , new Translation(1, 5)
                , new Translation(1, 6)
                , new Translation(1, 7)
                , new Translation(8, 9)
                , new Translation(8, 10)
            };
            var a = "cat";
            Console.Write("{0}: ", a);
            foreach (var w in TranslateWord(a, 1, 3)) Console.Write("{0} ", w); Console.WriteLine();
            var b = "cat goes";
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", b);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> kvp in TranslatePhrase(b.Split(), 1, 2)) {
                Console.Write("____{0}: ", kvp.Key);
                foreach (var w in kvp.Value)
                    Console.Write("{0} ", w); Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        static string[] TranslateWord(string word, int sli, int tid) {
            var tw = trns.Join(words, o => o.SrcId, i => i.WordId, (o, i) => new { i.WordName, i.LangId, o.TgtId })
                .Where(w => w.WordName == word && w.LangId == sli)
                .Join(words, o => o.TgtId, i => i.WordId, (o, i) => new { i.WordName, i.LangId })
                .Where(w => w.LangId == tid).Select(s => s.WordName).ToArray();
            return tw;
        }
        static Dictionary<string, string[]> TranslatePhrase(string[] phrase, int sli, int tid) {
            var twd = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
            foreach (string w in phrase) twd.Add(w, TranslateWord(w, sli, tid));
            return twd;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

cat: gato gata felino

cat goes:

____cat: kot kote kotiara

____goes: idzie

Comment: Thank you, but this would lead to three queries. First of all you have to fetch all `Word` entities matching given phrase. Next goes your query (changed to cover both "source" and "target" side, but this is trivial). Translation is just a binding though, so after fetching translations another query is needed -- fetching all words referenced by translations.

Comment: Approach with multiple tables is no go, consider dictionary with several languages -- with your approach I would need 2 extra tables per each pair of languages. It does not scale at all.

Comment: You can combine Word and Translation, but you need to change the structure whenever add the new language. In my solution you need add a Word and 2N Translation to add a new language to N already available ones, but you don't need to change any existing table.

Comment: I didn't say anything about combining Word and Translation. My point is I can have 100 languages with just main 2 tables -- Word and Translation (I need Language table listing all languages, but it does not affect the problem). So when I add new language I need to update Language table adding one record. With your approach not only I would add new tables but also search in multiple tables -- there is no way I could guess in which table I should look for phrases (e.g. "cat").

Comment: I am lost with your last update. This is about Entity Framework, not in-memory structures like List/Dictionary. When I query such structures using LINQ there is no "fix-up" optimization thus such problem never occur. So showing it works with regular LINQ is pretty obvious -- there is no problem there in the first place.

Comment: I proposed another solution. Just your question is ambiguous. If you are interested in the error only, you should provide 3x text less: model, code, and error message. It seems I paid attention at everything else. BR